# DateDiff() producing inaccurate answers

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to write a bit of code that will use the `DateDiff` function to get the difference in days between two dates. I will then use this number to determine where to enter data on my spreadsheet.

I have run into problems using the `DateDiff` function, so to try work out where I am going wrong I have gone to as simple as I could get, while still using variables but it is still not working.

The problem I am having is that it is not producing the answer in days or the answer is not accurate. For example, when running the code below VBA produces an answer of 24.

Where am I going wrong/what am I doing wrong?

```
 Dim DayValue As Date
 Dim YearStart As Date

 YearStart = DateSerial(Year(2016), Month(1), Day(1))
 DayValue = DateSerial(Year(2016), Month(1), Day(8))
 strong textMsgBox DateDiff("d", DayValue, YearStart)
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting the variables to see if they are as you expect?

Comment: @Burgi No, I had forgot to try that after rewriting the variables, for some reason yearStart is 31-Dec-1905 and DayValue is 07-Dec-1905

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the year, month or day functions inside the DateSerial Functions, and you need to switch the order of the arguments to the `DateDiff` function

Try this:

```
Sub test()
 Dim YearStart As Date

 YearStart = DateSerial(2016, 1, 1)
 DayValue = DateSerial(2016, 1, 8)
 MsgBox DateDiff("d", YearStart, DayValue)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
YearStart = DateSerial(Year(2016), Month(1), Day(1))
```

with:

```
YearStart = DateSerial(2016, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `DateSerial(2016, 1, 1)`

Using `DateSerial(Year(2016), Month(1), Day(1))` is a wrong approach, it tells to Excel:

- convert 2016 to a date (as Excel date format starts in 1900, 2016 is somewhere in 1905)
- get the year part of this date (1905)
- similarly also with month and day